# How to properly add user data using Bloc && How to properly use Google Places API

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api, bloc

I'm having difficulties in two areas:

1) When a user successfully logs into their account using phone auth in Firestore, I take them to an "Edit profile" page so they can add their profile information. I get an error saying that I can't add data to a null user class or add data to a class within a class.

I currently have my user class setup something like the following:

```
class User {

String points;
Name name;

User({this.points, this.name});

}

class Name {

String firstName;
String lastName;

Name({this.firstName, this.lastName})

}
```

As you can see, I have a class within a class and when I try to add a value, it says I can't. I've tried doing it like

```
_bloc.user.name.firstName = value
```

And I've tried like

```
Name newName = Name();
newName.first = value.
```

The second one seems to work but it doesn't seem right. I'm hoping you could help me understand how to properly approach adding data for new users when I have a class within a class.

The second issue is understanding how to properly use the Places API. I'm currently learning from the below repo, but it's outdated and there's a couple lines I can't seem to figure out how to change. I also can't seem to find an updated tutorial since the October app crashing update.

https://github.com/alfianlosari/flutter_placez

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This project shows for instance, how to make the logged in user available in different pages in your app: https://github.com/tattwei46/flutter_login_demo. It uses firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out and report back.